# change locale moment js

Tags: reactjs, momentjs

how to change date localization and displayed a new localized date?

```
const Locale = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => moment.locale("en")}>English</button>
      <button onClick={() => moment.locale("de")}>German</button>
      <p>{moment().format("LLLL")}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

codesandbox example https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-violet-v0hvf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a codesandbox with a working example https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-lumiere-97yto

In react if you want the component to re-render again you should make some changes to the state.

Answer (score 0):

```
const deMoment = moment().locale("de").format("LLLL");
const enMoment = moment().locale("en").format("LLLL");
const Locale = () => {
  const [momentDate, setMomentDate] = useState(deMoment);

  useEffect(() => {}, [momentDate]);
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setMomentDate(enMoment)}>English</button>
      <button onClick={() => setMomentDate(deMoment)}>German</button>
      <p>{momentDate}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Moment.js locale will only gets applied to new instance created after updating. So I have maintained the locale in state and I keep updating it on button click.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import moment from "moment";

const Locale = () => {
  let [loc, updateLoc]= useState("en")
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => updateLoc("en")}>English</button>
      <button onClick={() => updateLoc("de")}>German</button>
      <p>{moment.locale(loc) && moment().format("LLLL")}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Locale;
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to notify that `moment` object's locale is updated.

```
const Locale = () => {
  const [currentMoment, setCurrentMoment] = useState(moment().format("LLLL"));
  const updateMomentEN = () => {
    moment.locale("en");
    setCurrentMoment(moment().format("LLLL"));
  };
  const updateMomentDE = () => {
    moment.locale("de");
    setCurrentMoment(moment().format("LLLL"));
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={updateMomentEN}>English</button>
      <button onClick={updateMomentDE}>German</button>
      <p>{currentMoment}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

here after every time locale is updated, we are updating `currentMoment` based on new locale. Then `useState` does the notifying work.